# Does the guided encrypted LVM option encrypt swap on 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, encryption, system

After a bit of googling I still haven't managed to find a clear answer to this. If you use the guided encrypted LVM install option from the Ubuntu 11.10 Alternate cd (I think it's option 3), does it encrypt the swap partition automatically, as well as home? Leaving only the boot loader unencrypted? Or do I have to follow the various guides for older versions of Ubuntu for manually creating and encrypting swap and home partitions?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you use the guided option , everything but /boot will be encrypted.

How it works is that you have a series of containers. First is a physical partition. Within the partition is a crypt (LUKS) container. Within the LUKS you use LVM to divide the crypt into / and swap.

If you manually partition , make sure /home is also within the LUKS crypt / LVM.

So if you manually partition, you first make a LUKS crypt. Then within the crypt you use LVM to make / , swap, and if you so desire /home, but, with LUKS it makes less sense to have a separate /home as you can not as easily preserve an encrypted /home if you re-install. It is not impossible to do, just a few steps more difficult.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer! I'll go with the guided option.